# What is the common name for this type of multiple option journey?

Tags: forms, registration, onboarding, many-options

I stumbled upon this beautifully user-friendly, human-speaking quotation journey **[ceda-nepal.com/cost-calculator/](http://ceda-nepal.com/cost-calculator/)** and I couldn't find any article about this kind of journey.

I am currently designing a similar "quotation" journey that will help the stakeholders sort their users into 5 categories, and then direct them to different registration processes. I would like to see more example of same UI, and if possible get to the technical, common name used for this type of "multiple options journey" but couldn't find anything with these keywords.

Do you know how this structure is widely known as?

Can you recommend any literature/best practices when using them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That design pattern is a multi-branching **wizard**.

Wizards are ideal for walking users through steps to configure an application, service, or act as a more interactive form.

[UX Planet Article on Wizards and Best Practices](https://uxplanet.org/wizard-design-pattern-8c86e14f2a38)

[Additional article on Multi-Branching Forms](https://www.typeform.com/help/single-branching-vs-multi-branching/)

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer. The UX Planet article is exactly whats I was looking for, very thoroughly.

Comment: @ZenLoroVandereyck That’s great to hear :)